# How do I make WebStorm recognize a locally imported file when a script is being dynamically loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, development-environment

I have a node.js application that looks like this:

```
src/
src/app-loader.js
src/common/utils.js
src/plugin/index.js
```

app-loader.js dynamically loads `plugin/index.js` in such a way that the following code in plugin/index.js is valid:

```
import Thing from 'common/utils'
```

WebStorm flags that line as an invalid import, because from its perspective, `common/utils.js` would map to an npm package, and `./common/util.js` would map to `src/plugin/common/util.js`. It doesn't know about app-loader.js

How do I tell WebStorm to do it my way rather than what it normally does?  I've tried looking at the project Preferences and on the right-click context menu in the project pane, but nothing stands out as the right solution.  Ideally, if I <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on the import statement, it would also take me to the correct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all imports are resolved from the `src` folder, mark it as a "Resource root" from the folder context menu in Project view.
If you have more complex resolution rules that are described in a webpack configuration file, specify path to this config in the `IDE Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack`.

You can find more on the topic of imports in WebStorm in this [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/07/configuring-the-style-of-imports-in-javascript-and-typescript/).